# How to send content from Freemarker to java by request?

Tags: java, request, freemarker, magnolia

I'm trying send information from a FreeMarker template to my Java model class.

I've tried this:

```
//my array of string casted in a string
var pais = selected.join();

request.setAttribute(pais, "paises");
```

Ok, now I'm trying collect this content in my Java class doing this:

```
String paises = MgnlContext.getAttribute("paises");
```

But it doenst work. I tried other methods like this:

```
Stirng paises = MgnlContext.getInstance().getAttribute("paises");
```

But it always returns null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLUTION (sending info by ajax):

first get the values by javscript :

```
[#assign cpathx = ctx.contextPath]
[#assign url = model.getUrl() /] 
var field = $('#key').val();
var calin = $('#calendarIni').val();
var calfin = $('#calendarFin').val();
var pais = selected.join();
var url = '${cpathx}${url}?paises='+pais+'&palabra='+field+'&calendarini='+calin+'&calendarfin='+calfin;
    jQuery.post(url ,function(data) {
    jQuery('#ajax').html(data);
  });
```

Now we can collect the info in java:

```
String paises = MgnlContext.getWebContext().getAttribute("paises");
String queryString = MgnlContext.getWebContext().getAttribute("palabra");
String dateStart = MgnlContext.getWebContext().getAttribute("calendarini");
String dateEnd = MgnlContext.getWebContext().getAttribute("calendarfin");
```

Answer (score 0):

That first piece doesn't look like freemarker but more as JavaScript, so maybe that is your problem. While freemarker directives are executed server side, html and Js produced by freemarker is executed client side so w/o Ajax call there's no way for Js to talk back to server (and thus to model class).

If you were really interested in passing something from freemarker to java model, model is exposed directly.  You can simply add method in java model and call it from freemarker template like

```
${model.myMethod(someParam)}
```

HTH,
Jan